# How to perform multiplication on two column for datagrid view and assigning it in third column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Here is my code, I am trying to display multiplication of `Rate * Supply` column values and assigning it to the `Amount` column in data grid view :

```
try
{
    Query = "Select  id,Code,Description,Rate,Cust_Id,Supply,Empty,Amount,Received from Items ";
    adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds, "Items");
    dtgVOuchers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    ds.Tables[0].Columns["Amount"].DefaultValue = (ds.Tables[0].Columns["Rate"].DefaultValue) * (ds.Tables[0].Columns["Supply"].DefaultValue); //error

    //dtgVOuchers.Rows.Clear();
    ds.Tables[0].Clear();
    dtgVOuchers.Refresh();
}
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this functionality in data grid view ? . .Please help me to correct this code. Thanks

Comment: Note : i want to multiply in code not in query .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgVOuchers.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells[dtgVOuchers.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dtgVOuchers.Columns["Rate"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dtgVOuchers.Columns["Supply"].Index].Value));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the query

```
Select  id,Code,Description,Rate,Cust_Id,Supply,Empty,isnull(Rate,0)*isnull(Supply,0) as [Amount],Received from Items
```

Comment: SQL wasn't even tagged on this one so you may want to rethink your answer

Comment: yah i know but user didnt mention y he want to multiply in code instead that can be done easily in query.

Comment: Error : SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: Select  id,Code,Description,Rate,Cust_Id,Supply,Empty,isnull(Rate,0)*isnull(Supply,0) as [Amount],Received from Items [ near "isnull": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: @Terror.Blade - Haha... that's what happens when you assume an answer for a language with no standards. Good luck!

Comment: remove isnull just use rate*supply

Comment: M.babcock . Sir i m just trying to help. if you could appriciate. I am also a infant in this.

Comment: @Terror.Blade is right ! i want to multiply in code not in query .

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

      DataColumn quantityColumn = new DataColumn("Quantity");
      DataColumn rateColumn = new DataColumn("Rate");
      DataColumn priceColumn = new DataColumn ("Price");

      quantityColumn.DataType = typeof(int);
      rateColumn.DataType = typeof(int);

      myDataTable.Columns.Add(quantityColumn);
      myDataTable.Columns.Add(rateColumn);
      myDataTable.Columns.Add(priceColumn);

      //Set the Expression here
      priceColumn.Expression = "Quantity * Rate";
```

Comment: As i am  not adding column in data-table  .So please tell me how to write code for this scenario .Here i am trying like your code but it is giving error :                      ds.Tables[0].Columns["Amount"].Expression = (ds.Tables[0].Columns["Rate"].Expression) * (ds.Tables[0].Columns["Supply"].Expression);

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code..run a loop to update the Amount column in all rows

Note : Though this method is not preferred as it effects performance.So do this calculation in the sql query.I dont understand the reason behind not doing the munltiplication in SQL query..

```
  foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
       {
          row["Amount"]= Convert.ToDecimal(row["Rate"])* Convert.ToDecimal(row["Supply"]);
          ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();        
       } 
    dtgVOuchers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dtgVOuchers.Refresh();
```

Comment: Error : It is giving invalid cast exception ....Object cant be cast from DBNull to other types...........please help to remove this error

Comment: Edited the answer for you..Let me know in case of any issues.